# Assigning NA to the Matrix entries in R

Tags: r, matrix, na

I want to create a Matrix where the entry for each row is chosen randomly. I want the matrix to have the property that each row in the same column has a different value. If different rows (for example row i and row i+1) in the same column have the same value then I want to replace the entry for row i+1 with NA. Basically, I want the column to have different entries for each row. For example, column 1 entries are (1,2,2,4,1). Then, I want to make this column entries are (1,2,NA,4,NA). I have tried this

```
solution = matrix(NA,nrow=5,ncol=5)
for (i in 1:5) {
 for (j in 1:5) {
  one_entry  = sample(1:10, 1) 
  solution[j,i] = one_entry
  if (solution[j+1,i]==solution[j,i]){
   #is.na(solution[j+1,i]) <- solution[j+1,I]
   solution[j+1,i]<- NA
   #solution[solution[j+1,i]] <- NA
  } else {
    solution[j+1, i] = one_entry
  }
  }
}
print(solution)
```

I got the error "Error in if (solution[j + 1, i] == solution[j, i]) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". Please help how to resolve this.

Comment: `j+1` goes up to 5 but you only have 4 rows.

Comment: @AndrewGustar I edited already, but I think that's not the case here right? It works without the if condition. I am sure the problem is the NA thing, but idk how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of element-wise comparison using if statement, you can replace duplicated entries with NA. The output of `duplicated()` is a logical vector setting the position of the duplicates to TRUE.

```
set.seed(1)
nr <- 5
nc <- 7
m <- matrix(sample(1:10, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nrow = nr)
m

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    9    7    5    9    5    1   10
# [2,]    4    2   10    5    5    4    6
# [3,]    7    3    6    5    2    3    4
# [4,]    1    1   10    9   10    6    4
# [5,]    2    5    7    9    9   10   10

for (i in seq_len(nc)) {
  m[, i][duplicated(m[, i])] <- NA
}

m

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    9    7    5    9    5    1   10
# [2,]    4    2   10    5   NA    4    6
# [3,]    7    3    6   NA    2    3    4
# [4,]    1    1   NA   NA   10    6   NA
# [5,]    2    5    7   NA    9   10   NA
```

Comment: will it work for the non-square matrix? I tried it and it didn't work when I'm using the seq_len(ncol) or seq_len(nrow). Is there any specific reason? Also, this is not exactly what I want. I want  each column to have different entries for each row (or NA).

Comment: Yes - with some tweaks, it works for the non-square matrices too. I am not sure how you used seq_len(ncol). I might be able to give you more useful feedback if I saw your code. I have updated the answer based on your question. It looks more straightforward - using `duplicated()` would do.

Comment: Hi, this is what I want. I also find that using the unique() function also help remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Using `purrr` library:

```r
library(purrr)

set.seed(123)

#populate the matrix
(mat <- rerun(5, sample(1:10,size = 5, replace = TRUE)) %>%
        reduce(cbind))
#>      out elt elt elt elt
#> [1,]   3   5   5   3   9
#> [2,]   3   4   3   8   3
#> [3,]  10   6   9  10   4
#> [4,]   2   9   9   7   1
#> [5,]   6  10   9  10   7

map(2:length(mat), ~{ if (mat[[. - 1]] == mat[[.]]) .x } ) %>%
  compact() %>% 
  walk(~{ mat[[.x]] <<- NA })

mat
#>      out elt elt elt elt
#> [1,]   3   5   5   3   9
#> [2,]  NA   4   3   8   3
#> [3,]  10   6   9  10   4
#> [4,]   2   9  NA   7   1
#> [5,]   6  10  NA  10   7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It looks complicated for me. Also, I want each column to have different entries for each row (or NA). Thank you